# How do I get this code to stop at something non-numeric?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, minimum

I'm trying to make a program that prompts the user to enter numbers until a non-numeric value is entered. At that point, it ends and prints: count, sum, average, minimum, and maximum. I'm getting an "int cannot be dereferenced" error. I'm confused what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program3
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter an floating point number");
      int count = 1;
      int sum = 0;
      int min = 100000;
      int max = 1;
      int check=0;
      while(check==0)
      {
          int number = input.nextInt();
          if(number.hasNextInt())
          {
              count++;
              sum=sum+number;
              while(number<min)
                 min = number;

              while(input>max)
                 max = number;
          }       
          else
          {
              check=1;
          }
      }
      System.out.println("The count is " +count);
      System.out.println("The sum is " +sum);
      System.out.println("The average is " +sum/count);
      System.out.println("The minimum is " +min);
      System.out.println("The maximum is " +max);
      System.exit(0);    
   }
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't count the last number. I'm confused about that as well.

Comment: a primitive `int` is not an Object. There is no `hasNextInt()` method. You probably meant `input.hasNextInt()`

Answer (score 3):

```
int number = input.nextInt();
```

will give an exception if the next input is not an int.

a workaround would be to surround this statement in `try catch` block, and in the `catch` block do whatever you want to do after a `non numeric` is emcountered.

EXPLANATION for both problems: suppose you have

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 4
>
> a

when it encounters 4, it assignes `number = 4`, then checks if next value is also int ,

`if(number.hasNextInt())` , which is `false`, because next input is `'a'` , so this `if` block , which does processing on your `last encountered int`, does not run.

but, the `while` will still go to the next iteration, and would try to get an `int` out of the next input, i.e. , `a` and hence gives an exception

P.S: also i believe you intended to write `input.hasNextInt()` instead of `number.hasNextInt()`

Answer (score 2):

I would try to get a string from the user, and then parse it as a float. If I get an exception while parsing it as a float (or double), a non-numeric value has arrived.